# When does a float constant overflow if it is implicitly converted to int type

Tags: c, implicit-conversion

I have two code snippets and both produce different results. I am using TDM-GCC 4.9.2 compiler and my compiler is 32-bit version

( Size of int is 4 bytes and Minimum value in float is -3.4e38 )

Code 1:

```
int x;
x=2.999999999999999; // 15 '9s' after decimal point
printf("%d",x);
```

Output:

2

Code 2:

```
int x;
x=2.9999999999999999; // 16 '9s' after decimal point
printf("%d",x);
```

Output:

3

Why is the implicit conversion different in these cases?

Is it due to some overflow in the Real constant specified and if so how does it happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @ThomasJager Nope. That question discusses only the floating point arithmetic and not typecasting to int.

Comment: It discusses the representation of floats as being the nearest representable value.

Comment: @ThomasJager Thanks for the mention

Comment: Note: `2.999999999999999` and `2.9999999999999999` are both 'double' values, not 'float'  To make them 'float' they should be written as: `2.999999999999999f` and `2.9999999999999999f`   Note the trailing 'f'.  So your actually working with `double` values, not `float` values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Restricting this answer to IEEE754).

When you assign a constant to a floating point, the IEEE754 standard requires the *closest* possible floating point number to be picked. Both the numbers you present cannot be represented exactly.

The nearest IEEE754 double precision floating point number to `2.999999999999999`
is `2.99999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375` whereas the nearest one to `2.9999999999999999` is `3`.

Hence the output. Converting to an integral type truncates the value towards zero.

Using `round` is one way to obviate this effect.

Further reading: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Alagusankar: Pleasure, but do study the reference answer too. There are so many misunderstandings centred around floating point types out there.